# Why does construction with a function not cause a memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have a `matrix` class and a `transpose` function (which is not part of the class) which looks like this:

```
matrix transpose(const matrix& rhs) {
    matrix Rmat(rhs.nc(),rhs.nr());
    for(unsigned ir = 0; ir < rhs.nr(); ir++) {
        for(unsigned ic = 0; ic < rhs.nc(); ic++ ) { 
            Rmat(ic,ir) = rhs(ir,ic);
        }   
    }   
    return Rmat;
}
```

Now, when I declared `matrix At(M,M)` and then assign `At = transpose(A)`, I get a memory leak. However, when I create `At` as `matrix At(transpose(A))`, I do not get a memory leak. Why is this leak happening? As I cannot pinpoint where it is occurring, I may not have included enough information. If constructors/destructors are required, please ask and I will post them.

Comment: Assignment operator in `matrix` probably has a bug.

Comment: You haven't included enough information to be sure but the first form will invoke your `operator=()` and the second will invoke your copy constructor so I'd start looking for your problem there. Likely you are not freeing your resources in your assignment operator.

Answer (score 1):

If you wrote your `matrix` class, it is quite possible that your copy assignment operator or copy constructor has a memory leak. Per the *rule of three*, if you're going to define a destructor, then you need to also define copy assignment and copy constructor. Otherwise, you will get default copy assignment and copy constructor implementations that will not properly free any resources you allocated (e.g. with `new`).

To avoid these issues, you can use *standard containers* (e.g. `vector`, `list`, etc.) to store data, and/or *smart pointers* (e.g. `auto_ptr`, `smart_ptr`) to manage memory (semi-)automatically. These may save you from having to write a destructor (since the STL classes will clean up automatically), and thus save you from needing to also supply copy assignment and copy construction operations.